# Python3 skimage: undefined symbol: _gfortran_stop_numeric_f08

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ubuntu-16.04

I use Ubuntu 16 and installed scipy with `pip install scipy==1.1.0` so I could use `from scipy.misc import imread`

But now when I do `python3` and `from scipy.misc import imread`, I get this error

```
ImportError: /home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_stop_numeric_f08
```

yet, when I do `python` instead of `python3`, I don't get that error when importing imread

can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install scipy==1.1.0`? It's possible that you've installed `1.1.0` to different python

Comment: that fixes the error for `from scipy.misc import imread`, but when I do `from skimage.transform import resize` I get that same error as before

Answer (score 0):

There is some mixup between interpreters. To avoid this,

Always 1) prefer `python -mpip` with the python interpreter you want, 2) use virtualenvs, e.g. the standard library `venv` module.